# Conservation of momentum with magnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

Let's suppose you throw a $0.5$kg baseball at an armature of sliding magnets surrounded by metal coil that convert 100% of the kinetic energy into electrical energy. How is momentum then conserved? Can I claim its conserved because electrons get pushed in the direction of the magnets?

Comment: Momentum is conserved when there are no external forces.  Is your collection of magnets and coil fastened to the ground?

Comment: Note that you have to account for field momentum too. When the bookkeeping is done properly then momentum is conserved, as it must be

Comment: Never thought like that before! 